# Ignore missing ancestor JSON object keys in JavaScript/ES6?

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

When accessing value of a nested JSON object key, we need to check for existence of parent keys to prevent undefined key errors.

Given this:

```
var obj = {
  aaa: {
    bbb: {
      ccc: {
        ddd: 'ok'
      }
    }
  }
};

// #1 cause error if any of the parent key is not defined (e.g. aaa, bbb, ccc)
const ddd = obj.aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd || 'none';

// #2 this works but lots of repetition
const ddd = obj.aaa && obj.aaa.bbb && obj.aaa.bbb.ccc && obj.aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd || 'none';
```

In the example above, `#1` will not work if aaa, bbb, or ccc is not defined.

`#2` works but you see the repetition of ancestor keys.

Q: Is there a JavaScript/ES6 syntax to simplify this or we need to write/use a custom function?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification

Comment: You could implement something clever with ES6 Proxies, but otherwise there's nothing new in ES6 and you should use the existing solution

Comment: I don't think this is truly a duplicate. Too bad I can't post an answer. Destructuring with defaults helps a bit, though the syntax takes some getting used to:

`const { aaa: { bbb: { ccc: { ddd = 'none' } = {} } = {} } = {} }`;

Comment: @Jacob: Please post it as an answer at the canonical duplicate question.

Comment: @Bergi, will do, good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ES6 destructuring with default values to ease some of the burden:

```
const { 
  aaa: { 
    bbb: { 
      ccc: { 
        ddd = 'none' 
      } = {} 
    } = {} 
  } = {} 
} = (obj || {});
```

I certainly found this unintuitive at first. Here is the meaning broken down:

1. As the starting value, use `obj`, or if it is "falsy", `{}`.
2. Get the `aaa` property, or `{}` if undefined.
3. Get the `bbb` property, or `{}` if undefined.
4. Get the `ccc` property, or `{}` if undefined.
5. Declare a `ddd` constant, assigned the value of the `ddd` property, or `'none'` if undefined.

Note that default values during destructuring only applies to undefined values, not values like `null`; If you want to handle those cases, more traditional methods will have to be used.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a function I often make use of for JS default settings:

```
function defaultSetting(check,fallback,current)
    {
        if (!$.isArray(check)) {
            if ($.type(check) === 'string' && check.length > 0) {
                check = [check];
            } else {
                check = false;
            }
        }
        if (false === check || check.length < 1) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!current) {
            current = window;
        }

        var checkThis = check.shift();

        if (check.length > 0) {
            if ((checkThis in current) && $.type(current[checkThis]) === 'object') {
                return defaultSetting(check,fallback,current[checkThis]);
            } else {
                return fallback;
            }
        } else {
            if (checkThis in current) {
                return current[checkThis];
            } else {
                return fallback;
            }
        }
    }
```

It's actually not ES6 code so probably could be improved somewhat with ES6 syntax. It also uses jQuery for the $.isArray() and $.type() methods, but these lines could be replaced with `typeof` calls.

in your example above you would call it like `ddd = defaultSetting(['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd'],'none', obj);`

Answer (score -2):

You could use `JSON.stringify()`, `String.prototype.match()`

```
var hasKey = !!(JSON.stringify(obj).match(/"ddd":/));
```